# Is there a way to scope ID and IDREF to specific attributes?

Tags: xml, dtd

I'm trying to specify a DTD for an XML file.  But in it, I have two IDs used for different things.

I'd like to keep these IDs separate so that one tag's attribute that uses a IDREF must match the ID for a particular tag's attribute and another tag that uses a attribute IDREF must match the ID for another particular tag's attribute

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, ID/IDREF/IDREFS have document scope.

If you can use XSD instead of DTD, you can get more control over id scoping via `xsd:key` and `xsd:keyref`.