# Free XSD to DTD conversion utility?

Tags: xsd, dtd, converters

I have a XSD (XML Schema) that I need to convert to a DTD. Is there a free utility or simple way to accomplish this? A XSLT for example? Python scripts are welcome too.

**Note:** this is the opposite direction of the question [Free DTD to XSD conversion utility?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1510126/1513933)

I am aware that the conversion may lose information…

I tried XMLSpy or oXygenXML, but it is not free and I don't have the possibility to customize the conversion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

XMLPad (https://xmlpad.soft32.com/) claims

> Converting XSD to DTD and DTD to XSD.

I've never used it; your mileage may vary.

The Official website is: [wmhelp.com](http://www.wmhelp.com/)

Comment: This Windows tool works well. But still looking for a standalone solution (like XSLT or Python Script).

Comment: A comment from Семен from WmHelp.com: “XMLPad use custom XSD engine implemented on Delphi 7. I think that using XSLT for conversion XSD to DTD is a difficult task because XSD requires the type inference.”

Comment: The service is no longer available. As of 6-Feb-2023, the domain is parked with a scavenger (snaps up domains as the registrations expire, puts up a placeholder page, and waits for someone willing to pay for it.)

Answer (score 0):

I think there are limited number of people needed DTD if they have XSD.

For me, XSD is more usable then DTD, and I know some migrations from DTD to XSD, usually done manually, but I surprised you need opposite conversion done by script.

May be, you have to write or order the custom tool for your needs.

Comment: I use an old tool which only understand DTD.

Comment: Bad luck. May be you can find more recent tool with the same/similar functionality. It would be good solution as for me

Answer (score 0):

Technically, a complete conversion form XSD to DTD is not feasible. Even if you found a tool, you can not be sure that the results are same because there is some features in schema not exist in DTD . For example, [the problem of id scoping with IDREF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28286217/is-there-a-way-to-scope-id-and-idref-to-specific-attributes) in DTD.